# Why I can not Navigate to another page using button in Angular

Tags: angular

I can not Navigate to another page using button element in Angular. but if I write in browser that localhost:4200/about it works. My about path is

```
{path: 'about', component : AboutComponent},
```

component.html is:

```
<a mat-button routerlink="/about" routerLinkActive="active"><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [routerLink]="['/about']"
It should also be with capital L - routerLink

Comment: thanks..Main problem was Small- l It should be Link.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine if it's not dynamic

```html
<a routerLink="/about"></a>
or
<a [routerLink]="['/about']"></a>
```